# set background full in multiscroll js

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, multiscroll.js

i have a refference like this

http://reverzo.tymberry.com/

my code is like this

```
<div id="multiscroll">
    <div class="ms-left">
        <div id="home-left" class="ms-section slide-item full-width full-height fullscreen">
          <!-- <div class="container"> -->
            <p style="font-size:10em;">Lorem ipsum.</p>
          <!-- </div> -->
        </div>
        <div class="ms-section">Some section</div>
        <div class="ms-section">Some section</div>
    </div>
    <div class="ms-right">
        <div id="home-right" class="ms-section"></div>
        <div class="ms-section">Some section</div>
        <div class="ms-section">Some section</div>
    </div>
</div>
#home-left{

    background-image: url(http://www.reverzo.tymberry.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/furgona-home.jpg);
}

.slide-item.fullscreen {
    width: 200% !important;
}
.slide-item.full-height {
    height: 100%;
}
.slide-item.full-width {
    /*width: 100%;*/
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.slide-item {
    display: block;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
     background-size: cover; 
     background-position: center center; 
     background-origin: border-box; 
     background-repeat: no-repeat; 
}
#home-right{
    background: transparent;
}
```

heres my work

https://jsfiddle.net/ob1k3vut/
i wanna set the home image like that. its full screen. but when i scroll. the bakground didnt split. how to do that. it can make it full screen. but when scoling they still stick together.

i cant make the fiddle because i dont know the url of js and css of multi-scroll. so sorry guys. if you gus know the link off online css and js multiscroll, feel free to tell me. ill create it so u can check it

Comment: where you want to put background?

Comment: in #home-left sir. but same like the reference i put it in. i succes to make it full screen but doesnt split when scrolling

Comment: you need to set `background` on `#home-left`

Comment: i already set the background in #home-left in description

Comment: so you want to make full screen?

Comment: ya, i aldery make it full screen but when i scroll, the home-left and home-right stick together didnt go split.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107608/discussion-between-mmativ-and-vicario).